# Issue while compiling Cython code with distutils

Tags: python, gcc, cython, cythonize

I'm trying to compile Cython code and use it as Python module. I followed [Cython's basic tutorial](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html). I've made file hellowolrd.pyx:

```
print "Hello World"
```

I've made setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("helloworld.pyx")
)
```

and run:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

But unfortunatly an error has occured:

```
running build_ext
building 'helloworld' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -g -O2 -g -pipe -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -I/usr/include/ncursesw -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c helloworld.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/helloworld.o
gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--enable-new-dtags build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/helloworld.o -L/usr/lib64 -lpython3.5m -o /home/dima/Projects/AntennaModeling/test/helloworld.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-mageia-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../libpython3.5m.so when searching for -lpython3.5m
/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/libpython3.5m.so when searching for -lpython3.5m
/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libpython3.5m.so when searching for -lpython3.5m
/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.5m
collect2: error: command ld failed with exit status 1
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Seems that gcc not satisfied with python3.5 library. I've tried to compile without distutils with following commands:

```
cython -a helloworld.pyx
gcc -shared -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -I/usr/include/python3.5m -o helloworld.so helloworld.c
```

And it worked. From know i can import helloworld from Python interpreter. But i can't figure out how to make Cython code compiled with distutils. I've tried to pass the same flags using extra_compile_args but it didn't worked.

UPD:
  It found out that gcc can't find 64-bit library of python so tried to explicitly show library directory. So i changed setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

extensions = [
        Extension("helloworld", ["helloworld.pyx"],
        library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']),
        ]
setup(
    name = 'Hello world app',
    ext_modules = cythonize(extensions),
)
```

and still the same output

```
running build_ext
building 'helloworld' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -g -O2 -g -pipe -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -I/usr/include/ncursesw -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c helloworld.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/helloworld.o
gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--enable-new-dtags build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/helloworld.o -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib64 -lpython3.5m -o /home/dima/Projects/AntennaModeling/test/helloworld.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-mageia-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../libpython3.5m.so when searching for -lpython3.5m
/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/libpython3.5m.so when searching for -lpython3.5m
/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libpython3.5m.so when searching for -lpython3.5m
/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.5m
collect2: error: command ld failed with exit status 1
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: the problem is linking (second `gcc -pthread..`) and not compiling (on the command line you are compiling, not linking) it looks like you have a wrong type of libraries (32bit, wrong architecture?)

Comment: @ead, oh my, i thought i checked this, but i've mistaken. it seems my system has two python libraries for 32-bit architecture and 64-bit architecture. And by default it checks 32-bit librarry. I'll try to change path to lib in distutils. Thanks!

Comment: @ead. There is path to 64-bit libarary but linker doesn't say anything about it in the output.

Comment: I think cython uses something like `/usr/bin/python-config --ldflags` and this probably returns a wrong path

Comment: @ead, in the output frome above there is gcc flags "-L/usr/lib64 -lpython3.5m" and it is exactly where library is.

Comment: Thanks for telling, then I got it wrong. Looks like distutils magic gone wrong. I hope adding `library_dirs=['/usr/lib64']` to your setup solved the issue?

Comment: @ead, not, that didn't helped. Just output from /bin/ld was dupplicated

Comment: You can update the question with the current output

Comment: @ead, i did. But in my previous answer i added libraries = [python3.5], to my setup.py. That's why it was duplicated.

Comment: So there is no libpython3.5m in lib64, maybe without m?

Comment: @ead, full lib nama is "libpython3.5m.so.1.0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the linker searches for a library with name `libXXX.so`  and not `libXXX.so.1.0` (and if not successful, then for library with name `libXXX.a`). Usually `libXXX.so`  is a symlink to `libXXX.so.Y.0` which is the real library.

You can watch the linker working by calling the link-command with `-Wl,--verbose`, e.g.:

```
gcc -Wl,--verbose -pthread -shared -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--enable-new-dtags build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/helloworld.o -L/usr/lib64 -lpython3.5m -o /home/dima/Projects/AntennaModeling/test/helloworld.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

and you will see something like:

```
...
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libpython3.5m.so failed
...
```

So there are two options:

A: introduce symlink `/usr/lib64/libpython3.5m.so` on your system.

Or less intrusive B: add `libraries=[':libpython3.5m.so.1.0']` to your definition of extension:

```
extensions = [
        Extension("helloworld", ["helloworld.pyx"],
        library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']),
        libraries=[':libpython3.5m.so.1.0']
        ]
```

Now linking command should look a little bit different:

```
 gcc ... -L/usr/lib64 -l:libpython3.5m.so.1.0 ...
```

And the linker will be looking for `libpython3.5m.so.1.0`  and not only `libpython3.5m.so`  which is still provided by distutils.

Comment: Yes! That helped! Thnaks!